# Show Google Calendar in a Desktop App WebView similar to gmail sidebar iframe

Tags: webview, google-calendar-api, desktop-application

I am developing a **desktop app** for Windows/Mac and want to show a Google Calendar on the side of the main window inside a **webview** control.
Implementing a native calendar is not cost-effective at the moment so using the webview to show the users google calendar is a good option.

The result I would like to achiveve should be similar to what the web versions of Gmail/Drive etc offer when expanding the right - sidebar (see screenshot).

[image: Google Web Products Sidebars]

After inspecting the above webpage, google is using an iframe to show the side view. Unfortunately the URL used by this iframe is quite cryptic (with no documentation that I could find) and can't be used directly in a webview or outside of it's parent page (as far as I can tell).

Alternatively, just loading the mobile version of *https://www.google.com/calendar/gp* would seem as the go-to approach, but this version of the calendar web interface seems to be from 2010 and looks like it was designed for iPhone 3G :P (see screenshot). There does not seem to be any updated mobile web version as far as I can tell.

[image: Mobile web calendar outdated design]

Loading the desktop version of google calendar (which has the updated design) does not fit in the required width (see screenshot below).
[image: Desktop web calendar does not fit]

Is there any way I can load a google calendar so that it has no side menus, only a day view (designed for a tall and thin viewport) and that is not using a 2010 skin? Maybe there is some elusive documentation on how url query string params can be configured?

Comment: you may opt to use 3rd party applications to make it easy to embed mobile responsive calendars (if you are also looking for mobile version) as Daniel Ellis said: [How to embed mobile version of Google Calendar into mobile website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925629/how-to-embed-mobile-version-of-google-calendar-into-mobile-website)

Comment: or an embedded widget: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embedhelper. Then you can use the iframe code to integrate it.